# Series involving Laguerre polynomials

Tags: sequences-and-series, special-functions, contour-integration

Given the series
\begin{align}
S_{x}(a) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{k+1} \, \binom{x-1}{k} \, L_{k+n-1}(a)
\end{align}
where $L_{m}(x)$ is the Laguerre polynomial. 
By using 
\begin{align}
L_{n}(z) = \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \, \int e^{- \frac{z t}{1-t}} \, \frac{dt}{t^{n+1} \, (1-t)}
\end{align}
it can be determined that
\begin{align}
S_{x}(a) = L_{n-1}(a) + \frac{(-1)^{x}}{2 \pi i} \, \int e^{- \frac{a t}{1-t}} \, \frac{(1-t)^{x-2}}{t^{n+x-1}} \, dt
\end{align}

The question then becomes:

1. What is the closed form of the series ?
2. How is the remaining contour integral evaluated?